# How to fix slow sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making a wp guestbook and i've made a mistake somewhere. At first i've tried to use join but coud not get it to work properly because of all those conditions so i wrote this:

```
$query = "  
        (select *,
        (select count(cid) from ctable WHERE nid = vid) as posts,
        (select timestamp from ctable where nid = vid order by timestamp desc limit 1) as lt,
        (select count(vid) from ntable) as total
        FROM ntable
        )";
```

It does exactly what it supossed to do but it is very slow. I know i shout use join but i cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As per my Exp level ..try to use the nolocks as I updated your query that is ,

```
$query = '(select *,
        (select count(cid) from ctable with(nolock) WHERE nid = vid) as posts,
        (select timestamp from ctable with(nolock) where nid = vid order by timestamp desc limit 1) as lt,
        (select count(vid) from ntable with(nolock)) as total
        FROM ntable with(nolock)
        )';
```

and you are using the Order by for with timestamp column and instead of that use `getdate()-1`(means days count for the old data so that query will improve its performance.)

Comment: That returns error. It doesn't like the with(nolock) part.

Answer (score 0):

A join query might look like this (hard to be sure because you have not provided table definitions)

```
select *,p.posts,t.ts,(select count(*) from ntable) total 
 from ntable
 join (select vid,count(*) posts from ctable group by vid) p on p.nid = vid
 join (select vid,max(timestamp) ts from ctable group by vid) t on t.nid = vid
```

but assuming you have indexes on nid and vid I doubt if you will see an improvment - I would be interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. The problem is not in getting the data that is fast enough the problem is with order in with they are displayed (lt). that takes the longest.